# Linux: how to concatenate CSV files in an order and only keep the header of the first file to be concatenated?

Tags: linux, csv, header, concatenation

I need to concatenate some csv files that have a number at the end of their name as:

```
file1.csv, file2.csv, ..., file15.csv
```

These files have the same header, and I only want to keep the header of the first file.

After reading many posts I found a way to concatenate the files and keep the header, but the order of the concatenated files is not kept:

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}' file$*.csv > file.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong order is because wildcards are expanded in lexicographic order, not numeric order. You can get numeric order by using a range expression instead of a wildcard.

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}' file{1..15}.csv > file.csv
```

Or you could change your naming style to give them leading zeroes, `file01.csv`, `file02.csv`, etc.

See also [glob with numeric order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38317/glob-with-numerical-order) for other techniques.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! :)